# C# WebBrowserで意図しない余白が適用されてしまう

Tags: c#

同じHTML・CSSコードを通常ブラウザ(パソコンにインストールされているIE及びChrome)で閲覧した場合と、C# WebBrowserで表示した場合とで表示結果が異なってしまいます。
現象は以下の通りです。

[正常]　パソコンにインストールされているブラウザで表示
[image]

[問題] C# WebBrowserコントロールで表示
[image]

C#WebBrowserでは恐らくですがMarginプロパティがなぜか適用されているようで、横棒の縦間隔が広がってしまっているようです。

しかし、*{ margin:0; padding:0;} html,body{ margin:0;padding:0;}
このようにマージン、パディングを0に設定しても問題の現象は治りませんでした。

Nugetパッケージ CefSharpという別のブラウザコントロールを使うことも検討致しましたが
ライセンス関係加えて日本語の表示ができなく断念致しました。

もし何か少しでも原因・改善策問わずお分かりになられた方、ご教示頂けますようお願い申し上げます。

コードは以下の通りです。

C# WindowsFormsApplication

```
string html = @"<meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=edge"">
                 <meta http-equiv=""content-type"" charset=""utf-8"">
                 <meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=device-width, initial-scale=1"">
                 <style type=""text/css"">
                 <!--
                html, body {{ padding: 0; margin: 0 }}
                #humberger{
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: 24px;
                    width: 36px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    padding: 6px 0;
                    border: 2px solid #444;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                }
                #humberger div{
                    background-color:#444;
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: 4px;
                    width: 24px;
                    margin: 2px 6px;
                    border-radius: 2px;
                }
                --></Style>
                <div id=""humberger"">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>";

　　　　　　　　　webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

通常ブラウザでの確認用HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                 <meta http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">
                 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                 <style type="text/css">
                 <!--
                html, body {{ padding: 0; margin: 0 }}
                #humberger{
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: 24px;
                    width: 36px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    padding: 6px 0;
                    border: 2px solid #444;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                }
                #humberger div{
                    background-color:#444;
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: 4px;
                    width: 24px;
                    margin: 2px 6px;
                    border-radius: 2px;
                }
                --></Style>
                <div id="humberger">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
```

開発・実行環境
Windows8.1 64bit
Visual Studio Community 2017
Windowsフォームアプリケーション
IEバージョン：11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

既定ではWebBrowserコントロールは作成された当時のIE7モードで動作します。[Browser Emulation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation)で説明されているようにレジストリでこの動作を変更できます。どのような値が適切かはドキュメントを参照し検討してください。
なお、このレジストリ値はWebBrowserコントロールが読み込まれる前に設定されていればよいため、アプリケーション内で設定することも可能です。

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
>   SOFTWARE
>     Microsoft
>       Internet Explorer
>         Main
>           FeatureControl
>             FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
>               contoso.exe = (DWORD) 00009000
> ```

Comment: 回答頂き感謝申し上げます。<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">こちらのタグで最新ブラウザでの動作をしていると誤解しておりました。おっしゃる通り、レジストリの変更を行い最新バージョンのIEでの動作を行い、改善することができました。大変助かりました